# Div width not fit with child contents

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to fit the div with its contents using bootstrap.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12">
    <div style="<!--tried with inline-block float:left clear:left white-space:nowrap width:auto -->">
      <div class="span6">
        <table>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

nothing working with any of the styles. Please help me..

Comment: Have you tried so set div width the same as for .span12 ?

Comment: So width will become same as that of parent not content

Comment: Edits are not meant for you to plead for help. Please be patient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume by the classes you are using this is twitter bootstrap, if so, your markup is wrong.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12">
    <!-- span6 inside span12 will not use up 50% space unless it is the first child of a row --> 
    <div class="row-fluid"> 
      <div class="span6">
        <table>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, span* are floated, so unless they are inside a "row" element you need to use a clearfix div

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12">
    <div style="<!--tried with inline-block float:left clear:left white-space:nowrap width:auto -->">
      <div class="span6">
        <table>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And last, you can always try using a "overflow:hidden" on a container div to make it adapt to its floated children.

Comment: Thanks, will make changes as per the rule.